# Elixir macros: how to define function with dynamic arity

Tags: macros, elixir

refer this post: [How to create a dynamic function name using Elixir macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498528/how-to-create-a-dynamic-function-name-using-elixir-macro).

The post above asked how to use macro to generate function without arguments, but I wonder how to generate functions with some arguments ?

assume there is a macro `warp`, I could just write code like:

```
warp fun, [args], :ok
```

and then it generate code like:

```
fun(args), do: :ok
```

Comment: I's hard enough to find docs about ´unquote_splicing´. The title change may help future googlers like me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to generate a dynamic list of arguments, you need to use [`unquote_splicing`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1), like this:

```
defmacro warp(name, argument_names, code) do
  quote do
    def unquote(name)(unquote_splicing(argument_names)) do
      unquote(code)
    end
  end
end
```

Then later:

```
warp :foo, [a, b], {:ok, a, b}
```

which generates:

```
def foo(a, b), do: {:ok, a, b}
```

if you call that it will produce:

```
foo(1, 2)
# {:ok, 1, 2}
```

You can also define the macro like this without `unquote_splicing` and just pass down the combined name and arguments to `def`:

```
defmacro warp(name_and_args, do: code) do
  quote do
    def unquote(name_and_args) do
      unquote(code)
    end
  end
end
```

This means you need to invoke `warp` like you would invoke `def`, for example:

```
warp foo(a, b), do: {:ok, a, b}
```

Comment: This is so f'ing cool, great answer ty. But what if we DO want to invoke it like we would def (your very last line), but NOT in the single-line-of-code `, do: *1-line-only*` form (aka: `warp foo(a, b) do ... end` )

Comment: Nevermind. I'm pretty sure it will "just work". If I'm understanding right Elixir will accept the `, do: ...` or the `do ... end` versions the exact same. Ty for this awesome answer <3

Comment: @Bukov yep it’s just syntax sugar and Elixir will happily accept both variants. Thanks for your kind words

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example:

```
defmodule SomeMacro do
  defmacro warp(name, status) do
    quote do
      def unquote(name)(args) do
        {unquote(status), Enum.join(args, " - ")}
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule SomeModule do
  require SomeMacro
  SomeMacro.warp :something, :ok
end
```

And if you run it in IEX like this:

```
iex(1)> SomeModule.something([1,2,3])
{:ok, "1 - 2 - 3"}

iex(2)> SomeModule.something(["one", "two", "three"])
{:ok, "one - two - three"}
```