# Why is my dynamically defined function undefined?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to dynamically define some functions within the `__using__/1` macro of a module. These functions will have their names defined by the `opts` parameter provided to the `__using__/1` macro. Something like this:

```
defmodule MyModule do

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    names = Keyword.get(opts, :names)
    Enum.each(names, fn(name) ->
      quote bind_quoted: [name: name] do
        def unquote(:"function_for_#{name}")(param) do
          IO.puts("Hello from function_for_#{name}!")
          IO.puts("With parameter: #{param}.")
        end
      end
    end)
  end

end
```

Then, this module will be `use`'d by another module, like this:

```
defmodule UserModule do
  use MyModule, names: [:foo, :bar]
end
```

The behavior I would expect is:

```
iex> UserModule.function_for_foo(:hello_world)
> Hello from function_for_foo!
> With parameter: :hello_world.
iex> UserModule.function_for_bar(:hola_mundo)
> Hello from function_for_bar!
> With parameter: :hola_mundo.
```

But, instead, none of them are defined:

```
iex> UserModule.function_for_foo(:hello_world)
> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function UserModule.function_for_foo/1 is undefined or private
```

I've read some related documents for the last couple of days like: the [Kernel.use/2 documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2), the [Module documentation on compile callbacks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-compile-callbacks), an example provided in the [Domain Specific Languages documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html#storing-information-with-attributes), and [a very related question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498528/how-to-create-a-dynamic-function-name-using-elixir-macro), but I just can't seem to make this work.

Thanks in advance, any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: A best practice suggested in the Kernel documentation suggest that there should be no functions defined in `__using__`, then maybe my whole approach is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes here:

1. You need to return the quoted AST. `Enum.each` ignores the value returned by the function. You need to use `Enum.map` instead.
2. You missed an `unquote()` around `name` in this line:

   ```
   IO.puts("Hello from function_for_#{name}!")
   ```

Final code:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    names = Keyword.get(opts, :names)
    Enum.map(names, fn(name) ->
      quote bind_quoted: [name: name] do
        def unquote(:"function_for_#{name}")(param) do
          IO.puts("Hello from function_for_#{unquote(name)}!")
          IO.puts("With parameter: #{param}.")
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end

defmodule UserModule do
  use MyModule, names: [:foo, :bar]
end

UserModule.function_for_foo(:hello_world)
UserModule.function_for_bar(:hola_mundo)
```

Output:

```
Hello from function_for_foo!
With parameter: hello_world.
Hello from function_for_bar!
With parameter: hola_mundo.
```

---

> A best practice suggested in the Kernel documentation suggest that there should be no functions defined in **using**, then maybe my whole approach is wrong?

That's only when it's possible to define the functions in a module and just import it in `use`. Since you want to dynamically define the function names and bodies, you need to do that in `__using__` (or similar places like `@before_compile`).